# How can I permit an ArrayList from removing added objects without overriding or making it immutable

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Guys I have created an ArrayList and I don't want to make it immutable. I just seek to find a solution as for how to not allow the ArrayList from removing the objects.

```
public final class EMailArchive {

    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList <EMail> emailList;
    private final LocalDate date;


    public EMailArchive(String name, ArrayList <EMail> emailList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.emailList = emailList;
        date = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate( ) {
        return date;
    }

    public List <EMail> getEMailList() {
        return emailList;
    }

    public void addEMailToArchive(final EMail mail) {
        emailList.add(mail);
        // the mail added to the list shall not be removed, but how do i do that
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  If you have not provided the capability to remove objects from your arraylist, then how will it be possible for users to remove objects from your arraylist?

Comment: You could use a subclass that overrides the remove methods.

Comment: Oh, you mean you created an arraylist instance?  Yeah, Henry is right; just subclass and override the remove methods.

Comment: ok my description may be quite vague, so: i have a class called email archive which is immutable. it contains an arraylist with the type email and additionally there is a method called addEMailToArchive(final EMail email) in which i shall add an email to the arraylist. But once addded, it shall not be removed. Hopefully that clears things up sry

Comment: With this implementation, it's already impossible to remove an item from outside the class EMailArchive.

Comment: no its not... i have tried it

Comment: @vincrichaud On the second look he is right, as you could call e.g. `getEMailList().clear()` from the outside of the class.

Comment: @DorianGray @JiaxuanHE You're right. To prevent that, change your method `getEmailList()` to return a copy of the list

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Comment: yep thats why i removed getEmailList haha and therefore the problem is solved, beacuse you wont have the opportuniy to access the list.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to implement a subClass of ArrayList that override the remove method

```
class myArrayLit extends ArrayList {

    public myArrayList() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public remove(int index) {}

}
```

This is a basic example, there are more method to override, to achieve your goal.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion, but i have described the problem more precisely. I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: @JiaxuanHe reading through your precision, I don't see why extend ArrayList is a problem

Comment: @JiaxuanHe If you are not allowed to modify the type of the list, make sure no one can access it except through the methods you provide - that is, never expose/return the `ArrayList` to anyone

Comment: i have getter that returns the arraylist but that shouldnt be a problem

Comment: As @Hulk describes, this is the whole point of encapsulation: protecting your data from unwanted changes. There is no need to make the ArrayList final. Keep it private, and only implement public methods for what behaviors you want to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution above with extending `ArrayList` is not appropriate for whatever reason, you could return a copy within the getter, like this:

```
public List <EMail> getEMailList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(emailList);
}
```

Changes to the returned `List` will not be reflected back to the class member.